# Annotate FacetGrid pointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

How can I annotate a seaborn FacetGrid pointplot with the values of col1 "A" or "B" as a text, next to the points where they are drawn on "E".

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Data
a = list("ABC") * 4
c = list("DE") * 6
score = np.random.randint(-5, 5, 12)
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": a, "col2": c, "score": score})
print(df)

   col1 col2  score
0     A    D      4
1     B    E      2
2     C    D     -2
3     A    E     -3
4     B    D      4
5     C    E     -3
6     A    D      2
7     B    E      2
8     C    D     -5
9     A    E      1
10    B    D     -1
11    C    E     -3

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, hue="col1", height=5)
g.map(sns.pointplot, "col2", "score", **dict(order=["D", "E"]));
```

[image]

Desired outcome is with the labels A, B and C:

[image]

Comment: Just curious why you use `FacetGrid` if you only produce one subplot?

Comment: In the real dataset 'col1' would be 'country' and there is additional columns that can be used to split it by columns or rows. For instance I would like to split it by OECD countries and non-OECD countries, etc.

Comment: You may want to provide the most general case, where the `FacetGrid` is creating several subplots, because that would change how you'd write the solution. Also, please draw a mockup of what you expect the resulting graph to be. I can't figure out what you want to do with the third line, since you are only mentioning "A" and "B"